Hardhat Reporter is reporting empty report file
While running the gas report test, it displays an empty txt file.
Config file
require("@nomicfoundation/hardhat-toolbox");
require("dotenv").config();
require ("hardhat-gas-reporter");
// require("@nomiclabs/hardhat-waffle");


const { SEPOLIA_RPC_URL, SEPOLIA_PRIVATE_KEY, ETHERSCAN_API_KEY } = process.env;

module.exports = {
    solidity: "0.8.24",

    defaultNetwork: "hardhat",

    networks: {
        hardhat: {  },

        sepolia: {
            url: SEPOLIA_RPC_URL,
            accounts: [SEPOLIA_PRIVATE_KEY],
            chainId: 11155111
        },

        localhost: {
            url: "http://localhost:8545",
            chainId: 31337
        }
    },

    etherscan: {
        apiKey: ETHERSCAN_API_KEY,
    },

    gasReporter: {
        enabled: true,
        outputFile: "gas-report.txt",
        noColors: true,
        currency: "USD",
        coinmarketcap:"c11b4772-fd77-4a8a-81cd-0abc3dd051d0",
        showTimeSpent: true,
        showMethodSig: true,
    },

};

test file
const { ethers } = require("hardhat");
const {expect, assert} = require("chai");
const { SEPOLIA_RPC_URL, SEPOLIA_PRIVATE_KEY } = process.env;
const provider = new ethers.JsonRpcProvider(SEPOLIA_RPC_URL);
const fs = require('fs');
const wallet = new ethers.Wallet(SEPOLIA_PRIVATE_KEY, provider);


describe("SimpleStorage", function () {
    let SimpleStorageFactory, simpleStorage;
    const metadata = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync('./artifacts/contracts/SimpleStorage.sol/SimpleStorage.json').toString());
    
    beforeEach(async function () {
        SimpleStorageFactory = await ethers.getContractFactory(metadata.abi, metadata.bytecode, wallet);
        simpleStorage = await SimpleStorageFactory.deploy();
        await simpleStorage.waitForDeployment();
    });

    it("should start with the value 0", async function(){
        const currentValue = await simpleStorage.retrieve();
        const expectedValue = "0";
        // expect(currentValue).to.equal(0);

        assert.equal(currentValue.toString(), expectedValue);
    })

    it("should store the expected value", async function () {
        const expectedValue = "7";
        const transactionResponse = await simpleStorage.store(expectedValue);
        await transactionResponse.wait(1);

        const updatedValue = await simpleStorage.retrieve();
        assert.equal(updatedValue.toString(), expectedValue);
    }  );
})

